# How to choose the correct ibrav value and Identifying the 3-fold Axis

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, crystallography

I'm trying to perform relaxation calculations for FeTiO3 with the ilmenite structure in Quantum Espresso. The documentation mentions two possible ibrav values for triagonal systems: 5 and -5. However, I'm unsure which one is appropriate for my case. crystal constants are: a=b=c = 5.432 A, α=β=γ = 55.346^o.  Given these parameters, how can I determine the location and orientation of the 3-fold axis?